# Prove 2 simple expressions about probability

Tags: probability, statistics

1. $\sum_{r=0}^n C(n,r)p^{r}q^{n-r} = (p+q)^{r}$
2. $\sum_{k=1}^{10}\left(k^{2}\cdot \frac{k}{55}\right) = \frac{1}{55}\left(\frac{10\cdot11}{2}\right)^{2}$

I have started learn about basic-statistics and probability: 
when I solved the problem, solution only show about two expressions without any detail.

> How can I prove those expressions correctly? And is there any relation between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). There are proofs on Wikipedia.

The second uses the formula for the [sum of a sequence of cubes](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Cubes). Induction is the easiest way to prove it. If you haven't learned about induction, I'm not sure that you'd be expected to be able to prove that formula.